# Column Comparison in Power BI dax

Tags: powerbi

I'm starting Power BI.
And I need to count ids but there are duplicates because an id can have several statuses (Notifed, success...) and I want if the id has a notified and success status not to count it
I'm trying to compare the ids based on the statuses but I have no idea.
I'm trying to compare the ids based on the statuses but I have no idea.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please try to explain with sample data in text format with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VAR NotifiedID=
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(pressureStatusHstory[_id])
            ,pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Notified"
            ,MONTH(pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1 
        )

VAR SuccessID=
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(pressureStatusHstory[_id])
            ,pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Success"
            ,MONTH(pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1 
        )
        
VAR EndedID=
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(pressureStatusHstory[_id])
            ,'pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Ended"
            ,MONTH(pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1 
        )
VAR NoSuccess=
        EXCEPT(NotifiedID,SuccessID)

VAR NoSuccessNoEnd=
        EXCEPT(NoSuccess,EndedID)
        
RETURN CountRows(NoSuccessNoEnd)
```

Exactly this code can be shorter:

```
VAR NotifiedID=
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(pressureStatusHstory[_id])
            ,pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Notified"
            ,MONTH(pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1 
        )

VAR SuccessAndEndID=
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(pressureStatusHstory[_id])
            ,OR(
                pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Success"
                ,'pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.status]="Ended"
             )
            ,MONTH(pressureStatusHstory[statusHistory.date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1 
        )

VAR NoSuccessNoEnd=
        EXCEPT(NotifiedID,SuccessAndEndID)
        
RETURN CountRows(NoSuccessNoEnd)
```

This is not only solution for the case.

Comment: With This method also counts the ids that appear in Notified when they are already in success. But what we want is to count the ids that have remained in Notified status only

Comment: I added some correction and comments to the post.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: I did this kind of measures but the result is not correct. Let me show How I Do that